# How to fix "/lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found"?

Tags: c++, linker

I compiled a binary and copied on another machine for execution. But I am getting the above error. On the second machine, I cannot install new libraries. I tried putting the libc from the first machine into the directory of the binary on the second machine, but the linker (as I found using ldd) still loads from the standard path /lib/tls/libc.so.6). Please let me know a least change fix for this.

Update:

Command used for compilation/linking:

> g++ -O2 -DNDEBUG  -o CountStrings
>   -I../../../../../tbb/tbb20_20080408oss_src/include/ ../src/CountStrings.cpp
>   -L../../../../../tbb/tbb20_20080408oss_src/build/linux_ia32_gcc_cc4.3.2_libc2.8.90_kernel2.6.27_release/
>   -ltbb

libtbb.so has dependency on libc.so.6

Comment: Can you post your compiler and linker commands?

Answer (score 3):

In fact the easier way to fix the issue is to **upgrade your OS version**.

For example, Java 1.7 is not running on RedHat 4 but works well on RedHat 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<location_of_your_lib>` for your process
e.g. `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/kumar ./a.out`
will look for libs in `/home/kumar/` before anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if there is a static version of the library on the compilation machine?  If there is you could explicitly link against it, using /lib/tls/libc.a instead of -L/lib/tls -lc (or whatever your dialect is).

Comment: Or possibly just try to link the whole binary statically, by passing the -static argument to either ld or gcc.

Comment: I tried linking statically, but the library does not have a static version. The compilation just quits, saying "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltbb"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what (ill) side effects it may have to use another libc than provided by the system, but you can try to force using your special libc copy with [LD_PRELOAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)

```
LD_PRELOAD=<location_of_your_lib> <yourprogram>
```